# jQuery Prevent Form Submission, then Submit After Serialization

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to do the following with jQuery:

1. Prevent form submission
2. Serialize certain elements of the form into an array
3. Submit the form via PHP.

Here is my jQuery so far;

```
entrySubmit.on('click', initEntrySubmission);

function initEntrySubmission(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var serializedProtocol = $("#protocolForm :input").serialize();
    console.log(serializedProtocol);
    $('#protocolValues').val(serializedProtocol);
    $('#entryForm').submit();

}
```

The form prevents submission and serializes the array properly, but then does not do anything past that. The submission part seems to be the only thing not working. All documentation I've seen online says to use the last line there, but no dice.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks for any help,
Nick

Comment: So it is confirmed that `console.log(serializedProtocol)` show correct data and `$('#protocolValues').val(serializedProtocol)` works correctly?

Comment: Yes, it does work perfectly. i.e. "Name+of+Item=aa&Item+Description=a&Room+%23=ABCa&Box+or+Rack+Identifier=aaaaaaaaaa&General+Location+Description=aaaaa"

Comment: Actually, how can I check if the hidden form (#protocolValues) is set? In other words, how can I confirm that the line of code prior to submission is working?

Comment: $('#protocolValues').val(); in console returns 'undefined', leading me to believe its not working?

Comment: There you get to the point...

Comment: Alright so I got the hidden field value assignment working, but submission is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below

```
<form id="form1" action="test.php" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input name="name2" id="protocolValues" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var serializedProtocol = $("#form1 :input").serialize();
        $('#protocolValues').val(serializedProtocol);
        $('#form1').removeAttr('onsubmit');
        $('#form1').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, same as before where clicking the submit button logs my serialized array, but doesn't submit